# Automatically move up/down answers when I vote up/down them

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, sorting

I tried to search if this was asked before, but couldn't find anything...

By default, when I'm in a specific question page, I see answers sorted *by votes*. If there are two answers `A` and `B` which have the same votes, and **I vote up/down** one of them, it would be great to **automatically move it up/down** in the list.

**Is it something that could be implemented?**

I only see a problem in this:

That the votes of any of those answers changed during that time, but anyway, it could be sorted according to the new votes of each one... don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really see the immediate advantage of this: once you reload the page, the answers will be ordered according to the correct order (even taking note of votes by other users since the last re-load).

It would even have a drawback, when I want to read all answers and vote for one after I read it: my position inside the page will be changed and I when I skip to the next answer it will be a "previous" one.

My vote: don't implement this.

Comment: I agree with you. I didn't think about what would happen if I want to read all answers from top to bottom :)